# JTable, data, non static method

Tags: java, jtable

What's the problem? Non-static variable data cannot be referenced from a static context. I would like to load data from .dat file, but I don't know how can I do it? I tried it but it doesn't work because of the previous error message. Thank you for the helping.

```
  public class StudentFrame extends JFrame {
    private StudentData data;
    private static String[] columnNames = {"A","B","C","D"};
        private void initComponents() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public StudentFrame() {
            super("Hallgatói nyilvántartás");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            try {
                data = new StudentData();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("students.dat"));
                data.students = (List<Student>)ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    try {
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("students.dat"));
                        oos.writeObject(data.students);
                        oos.close();
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            initComponents();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StudentFrame sf = new StudentFrame();
            sf.setVisible(true);


            sf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


            JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);//PROBLEM

            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
           /*Jscroll...*/

            scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
            sf.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            sf.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            sf.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            sf.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try: private static StudentData data; instead of: private StudentData data;

Comment: Please format your question, make it clear what compiler error you get on which line. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- better questions tend to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest restructuring your code and moving the contents of the main method into your StudentFrame class. There is no real reason to use static variables, make TableData a member variable of StudentFrame. Only instantiate StudentFrame from main method, set up the frame and display it. how the contents are displayed should be part of the StudentFrame class.

columnNames is fine as a static, as its a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your StudentFrame private member variables need public accessors and then you would reference them in main as `JTable table = new JTable(sf.getData(), StudentFrame.getColumnNames());`